# Guice: Inject class with constructor with own parameters?

Tags: java, guice

I have a problem with Guice. I would like to show this with an example. I want to pass the parameters of this constructor always dynamically, so e.g. new Test("bob", 765);. I also want some fields (like here SomeOtherObject) to be injected by Guice. How can I do this? Thanks in advance!

```
public class Test {

private String name;
private int id;

//Needs to be injected by Guice
@Inject
SomeOtherObject object;

public Test(String name, int id) {
    this.name = name;
    this.id = id;
}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guice's [AssistedInject](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/AssistedInject) feature is a good way to handle this.

Basically you define a factory to get `Test` objects with:

```
public interface TestFactory {
    public Test create(String name, int id);
}
```

Augment the `Test` class's `@Inject` constructor with `@Assisted` annotation:

```
public class Test {
    @Inject
    public Test(SomeOtherObject object, @Assisted String name, @Assisted int id) {
        this.object = object;
        this.name = name;
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

And then use `FactoryModuleBuilder` in your Module's configure:

```
install(new FactoryModuleBuilder().build(TestFactory.class));
```

And instead of constructing `Test`s directly, inject a `TestFactory` and use it to create `Test`s:

```
public class OtherThing {
    @Inject
    TestFactory factory;

    public Test doStuff(Stirng name, int id) {
        return factory.create(name, id);
    }
}
```

Note: looking at the docs now, it appears that [AutoFactory](https://github.com/google/auto/tree/master/factory) has been introduced as the preferred way to do this, and may be simpler.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is exactly what I was looking for.